# Is the set of connected components of a basis another basis in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau_u)$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to prove the following result of basic topology:

> Let $\mathbb{B}$ be a basis of the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$: $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau_u)$. Let $\mathbb{B}'$ be the set of the connected components of elements in $\mathbb{B}$. Then $\mathbb{B}'$ is also a basis of $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau_u)$.

I have tried the usual strategy of proving that a subset is a basis of a given topology:

> 1. Prove that $\mathbb{B}'\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
> 2. Prove that, given $O\in \tau_u$ and $x\in O$, it exists some $B\in \mathbb{B}'$ that $x\in B \subset O$.

It is clear that $\mathbb{B}'\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, but I don't know how to prove the second point.

Could you help me, please? Thank you!

Comment: I think you have #2 backwards. You start with $O \in \tau_u$ and try to find $B\in \mathbb{B}$ such that $x\in B \subset O$.

Comment: As far as I know basis of a topology has to be formed by open sets, but conneceted compenents are closed.

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto The connected components of a space are both closed and open.

Comment: @MattPressland You are right, but that's not general. Is the case we are dealing is true, because the euclidean spaces are locally connected. (This has to be proven.)

Comment: @JosuéTonelli-Cueto Ah, true. I had forgotten this doesn't work when there are infinitely many components.

Comment: Oh, you're right, @Prahlad. I'll edit it, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by connected components of a basis?

Comment: A connected component of a set is a maximal connected subset (it's connected and every set that include it is not connected). So $\mathbb{B}'$ is the set that contains all the connected components of $\mathbb{B}$

Comment: But then it should rather be called the connected components of the elements of $\Bbb B$, not the connected components of $\Bbb B$.

Comment: Also #1 cannot be. $\Bbb B'$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2.$

Comment: @StefanH, the elements of $\mathbb{B}'$ are the connected components of the set $\mathbb{B}$, that form a partition of $\mathbb{B}$ itself, so it's clear that $\mathbb{B}'\subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: No $\Bbb B'$ is a set whose elements are subsets of $\Bbb R^2$, so it cannot be a subset of the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will develope azarel's hint, but really the fundamental idea is his/hers.

1) $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau_u)$ is locally connected, i.e. all open balls are connected. (This is the fundamental point of the argument.)

2) Use $1)$ to show that the connected componets of $B\in\mathbb{B}$ are open in $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau_u)$. Thus $\mathbb{B}'\subseteq \tau_u$, i.e. is a set of open sets of $(\mathbb{R}^2,\tau_u)$.

3) Use the definition of $\mathbb{B}'$, to show that every set of $\mathbb{B}$ is an union of sets of $\mathbb{B}'$.

4) Use $3)$ and the fact that $\mathbb{B}$ is a basis for $\tau_u$ to show that $\mathbb{B}'$ is also a basis.

Comment: I am still working on this, I think I haven't understood it well.

The first point is clear, I think the second too: the connected components of $B\in \mathbb{B}$ are union of connected sets that contain $B$. Since the open balls are connected, the connected components of $B$ are open balls and a union of open balls with intersection nonempty is open in $\tau_u$, isn't it?

But I don't understand the third point: I thought that every set of $\mathbb{B}'$ were a union of sets of $\mathbb{B}$, not like you said. Where am I wrong?

Thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: For the second, you have to take a connected component $C$ of a set $B$ in $\mathbb{B}$. Then, given $x\in C$, since $B$ is open, there is some open ball $B(x,r_x)$ contained in $B$; but $B(x,r_x)$ is connected and has no empty intersection with $C$, therefore, it has to be contained in $B$. This shows that the connected components are open, the connected components can be no balls.

Comment: For the third, don't you remember that for every set $X$, $X=\bigcup_{x\in X}C_x$ where $C_x$ is the connected component of $x$ in $X$. Imagine that $B((0,0),1)\cup (2,3)\times (8,9)$ is an open set of $\mathcal{B}$. Then $B((0,0),1)$ and $(2,3)\times (8,9)$ are in $\mathbb{B}'$ and the original set is an union of these two. I hope this last example will illustrate the point.

Comment: Ok ok, I've got it now, the example is very clarifying. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: An open ball is connected.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I don't really know how the connected components of $\mathbb{B}$ are. Because, by definition, if A is a connected component, then every set C that contains A ($A\subset C$) is **not** connected. Thinking like that, there's no connected component contained in an open ball (since it's connected).

Where am I wrong? Thank you for your patience.